# Creating Cross Object Formula Field

Tags: formula-field

Do i have to create a look up or master-detail relationship between 2 objects before a cross object formula field can be created.

Please help

Answer (score 2):

There needs to be a relationship between the two objects if you want to create a formula field to grab data from a "parent" record. You don't necessarily need to create that relationship (i.e. A relationship between `Opportunity` and `Account` already exists as the standard `AccountId` field on `Opportunity`), but there does need to be a relationship.

That relationship field also needs to be populated on a given record before you'll see a value appear in the formula field for a given record, and cross-object formulas only work to grab data from higher in the relationship heirarchy.

i.e. on a "child" Opportunity, you could pull data from its "parent" account record. You can't go the other direction, from Account to Opportunity, as there could be multiple Opportunities related to that one Account (and formulas have no way to say "use record #x").